# Checking my proof for the following power set problem.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am unsure if my proof for this is correct. Need verification, please!

Show that the condition A = B is not a necessary one for $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ by finding examples of sets A and B such that $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ but $A \ne B.$

Let A = {1,2} , B={1}

$P(A)$ = {{1},{2},{1,2}, $\varnothing$}

$P(B)$ = {$\varnothing$ , {1}}

$P(A)\cup P(B)$ = {$\varnothing$ , {1}, {2}, {1,2}}

$A \cup B$ = {1,2}

$P(A\cup B)$ = {$\varnothing$, {1}, {2}, {1,2}}.

Thus, $P(A\cup B)$ = $P(A) \cup P(B).$ However, $A \ne B$.

Answer (score 2):

If you take $A$ nonempty and $B = \varnothing$, then you have it all.

Comment: Hi Mr. Gregori, thank you for your response. Is that all it is for the answer? If so wow, that was short!!!

Comment: I came up with this solution to the problem. Do you believe my answer is correct?

Comment: Hi @bengraham12 !  If you need only particular examples, the solution given by Andrés E. Caicedo (or yourself, and I cannot see it well) is perfect.

Comment: Hi again ! In general, if B is a subset of A, then: (1) AUB=A; (2) P(AUB)=P(A); (3) P(B) is a subset of P(A) because all the subsets of B are also subsets of A; (4) P(A)UP(B)=P(A). Finally, from (2) and (4) you get that both thing are the same thing.